# How to connect mysql to node js using XDevAPI connector with 3306 port

Tags: node.js, mysql-connector

I installed XDevAPI for connecting mysql and nodejs. but it throw error like "The server gone away" because i am using 3306 port. how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Port 3306 defaults to the classic MySQL Wire Protocol. The MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js only supports the X Protocol, which is implemented by the X Plugin (by default on port 33060).

You can change this by updating the `mysqlx_port` server variable or using the `--mysqlx-port=` option when starting the server. If you want to use the X Protocol on port 3306 though you will also have to update the `port` variable or use a different value with the `--port=` option when starting the server.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js